# Azure Table Storage get last record

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I have an azure table with about 5 million+ rows, each partition about 100k rows. The RowKey is a sortable timestamp. I need to be able to get the latest record that was inserted in the table.

Since Linq Last, Max, OrderBy etc are not supported, how do I efficiently get the most recent table record?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's no efficient way to do this. But if it's an option, consider flipping your row key so that the newest entries are on the top (reverse chronological order). Retrieving the top *n* entries is easy and efficient.

Comment: And a good reference to achieve this is one of your old blog posts: http://blog.smarx.com/posts/using-numbers-as-keys-in-windows-azure

Comment: Any idea if the azure team will add support for more Linq queries for table storage? Or are the technical limitations too complex...

Comment: I would expect more queries to be supported over time, but probably not this one. With my understanding of how the data is stored, there's no good way to get to the end of the list or otherwise query in reverse order. (Think kind of like a singly-linked list.)

Comment: Let's hope they add indexes some day.

Comment: If there's really no efficient way to get the last entry, isn't that pretty telling as to what a poor product Azure Table Storage is?

Comment: @KenSmith it shows you might have chosen the wrong tool for the job

Comment: Agreed. But among other things, it shows that the jobs Azure Table Storage is a good fit for is extremely limited.

Answer (score 3):

[Log tail pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/tables/table-storage-design-patterns#log-tail-pattern) section of Microsoft's [Table design patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/tables/table-storage-design-patterns) specifically addresses this:

> *Context and problem*
>
> A common requirement is been able to retrieve the most recently created entities, for example the 10 most recent expense claims submitted by an employee. Table queries support a $top query operation to return the first n entities from a set: there is no equivalent query operation to return the last n entities in a set.
>
> (...)
>
> The following C# code sample shows one way to create a suitable "inverted ticks" value for a RowKey that sorts from the most recent to the oldest:
>
> `string invertedTicks = string.Format("{0:D19}", DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks - DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks);`
>
> (...)

Answer (score 2):

You can query for TimeStamp smaller than MaxDate and limit the result for 1.
Haven't tested it yet but it should work.
Depends on how is your time stamp formatted.